# How to add aggregate value to SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm selecting data from multiple tables and I also need to get maximum "timestamp" on those tables. I will need that to create custom cache control.

```
tbl_name     tbl_surname
id | name    id | surname
---------    ------------
 0 | John     0 | Doe
 1 | Jane     1 | Tully
  ...          ...
```

I have following query:

```
SELECT name, surname FROM tbl_name, tbl_surname WHERE tbl_name.id = tbl_surname.id
```

and I need to add following info to result set:

```
SELECT MAX(ora_rowscn) FROM (SELECT ora_rowscn FROM tbl_name
UNION ALL
SELECT ora_rowscn FROM tbl_surname);
```

I was trying to use UNION but I get error - mixing group and not single group data - or something like that, I know why I cannot use the union.

I don't want to split this into 2 calls, because I need the timestamp of the current snapshot I took from DB for my cache management. And between select and the call for MAX the DB could change.

Here is result I want:

```
John | Doe   | 123456
Jane | Tully | 123456
```

where 123456 is approximate time of last change (insert, update, delete) of tables tbl_name and tbl_surname.

I have read only access to DB, so I cannot create triggers, stored procedures, extra tables etc...

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: The value *ora_rowscn* is assigned per block of rows. So in one table this value can differ per row. I need the maximal value from both (all) tables involved in query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT name, 
       surname, 
       max(greatest(tbl_name.ora_rowscn, tbl_surname.ora_rowscn)) over () as max_rowscn
FROM tbl_name, tbl_surname 
WHERE tbl_name.id = tbl_surname.id
```

Comment: Thanks this done the job. Sorry for delay, your answer is accepted now.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to aggregate here - just include both ora_rowscn values in your query and take the max:

```
SELECT 
  n.name, 
  n.ora_rowscn as n_ora_rowscn,
  s.surname,
  s.ora_rowscn as s_ora_rowscn,
  greatest(n.ora_rowscn, s.ora_rowscn) as last_ora_rowscn
FROM tbl_name n
join tbl_surname s on n.id = s.id
```

BTW, I've replaced your old-style joins with ANSI style - better readable, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it guaranteed that greatest() will select maximum ora_rowscn from both tables? For me it looks like it will take maximum ora_rowscn per row in result.

Comment: Greatest will return the maximum per row. So you want the maximum ora_rowscn over both tables (which will be identical for all rows) ?

Comment: I need maximum from both tables. The problem with ora_rowscn is that rows in tables can have different ora_rowscn number. Because this number is assigned per row block not per table as explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm and here http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:517105100346104196

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. In your example above, if you have these SCNs: John 1, Doe 2, Jane 3, Tully 4 - do you want 4 for both? Or 2 for John and 4 for Jane?

Comment: I need maximum from both (all) tables involved in query. So in your example data I want 4 for all rows in result set.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest analytic functions (partition by) - see Mark Bannister's answer.

Comment: Mark Bannister's solution worked as expected. Thanks for patience and sorry for delay.